# When, if ever, would you expect classes marked as obsolete to be removed from the .NET framework?

Tags: .net, deprecated, obsolete

As we approach the 4th major release of the .NET framework we are likely to see an increase in the number of classes and methods marked as obsolete (to indicate they are deprecated). I found this page listing all the [obsolete members](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee471421(VS.100).aspx) and [types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee461503(VS.100).aspx), which is growing quite large now.

So, I was wondering whether:

1. Have any members or types marked as obsolete have been actually removed from any version of the framework? Are there elements from, say, .NET 1 that are not in later versions at all?
2. Are there any formal guidelines Microsoft follow as to when elements will be removed? Is this after *X* number of releases? Elapsed time? Or is it likely deprecated elements will remain in perpetuity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with removing an obsolete class from the Framework is that it becomes a *breaking change* to applications built against the Framework, whereas applying `ObsoleteAttribute` is not.

Consequently, I don't expect to see any of those classes marked obsolete removed any time in the near future, if ever.

Answer (score 2):

The most reasonable way would be to leave them there forever in order to keep backward compatibility.

Comment: Wouldn't that lessen the incentive for people to use alternatives, though? I thought the idea was that if people wanted to use these methods they would have to target an earlier version of the framework.

Comment: It might but it's better than simply screw them all at once. Anyway, scary hundreds of warning messages (deprecated) during compile should compel most good developers to update their stuff.

Comment: ObsoleteAttribute is a great mechanism for pointing people to the newer/better code without breaking earlier code.  The incentive to use the non-obsolete code would presumably be the efficiency/features/ease of use over the obsolete implementation.