# .net framework Obsolete methods - when will they be removed?

Tags: .net, frameworks, methods, obsolete

I have been tasked with recompiling an application from .net 1.1 to .net 4.0.

I have been told to not make any code changes - however with all the changes through the versions of the framework - I am reluctant to leave in methods that are marked as Obsolete.

Microsoft's website states that obsolete methods are left in for backwards compatability with the previous framework version but also as a warning that in the future they will be removed - my question "When will they be removed?"

Comment: I don't think you'll get anything better than "Whenever MS feels like it".

Comment: possible duplicate of [When, if ever, would you expect classes marked as obsolete to be removed from the .NET framework?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1612256/when-if-ever-would-you-expect-classes-marked-as-obsolete-to-be-removed-from-th)

Answer (score 2):

There is no set time frame for when a particular `Obsolete` method will be removed.  Generally the process of removing a method goes as follows

- Mark the method as `Deprecated` in a major release
- Mark the method as `Obsolete` in a future major release
- Remove the method in a future major release

Given that there are only 4 major release of .Net 4.0 is really the first version where a method could be removed by this process.  I don't know off hand how many, or any, methods have actually been removed from the BCL but I suspect the number is small.

Comment: This was my concern. I was hoping there was a plan for say functionality that became deprecated in 2.0, to be phased out(obsolete 3.0, removed 4.0). However it still works in 4.0 so do i persist with it as the client does not want changes to the code. My argument that it will be removed at some point but i dont know when is pretty weak. I know it needs to be removed and recoded but the business is reluctant to change. I am wary as 4.5 is around the corner, if i leave the functionality in and it is removed in 4.5, the project of preparing for the future instantly becomes a failure.

Comment: @Ben I'd say it's **very** unlikely an API would every be removed in a point release.  That would be too much of a breaking change. I would only expect it to be removed in a major release (but then again, I don't make the rules :) ).

Comment: i have downloaded the Dev previews of 4.5 and all functionailty that i have showing as obsolete is still present and working - so at least i am safe for a couple of years :-)

Answer (score 1):

That's up to MS, but my guess is never unless they are broken.

MS places a high priority on backwards compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is known or published in advance, it's just a heads up that they might disappear in a future release.